# Get value from string in IEnumerable

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable

I have the following code

```
    public const string boy = "B";

    public const string girl = "G";

    private gender(string description, string value)
    {
        Description = description;
        Value = value;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<gender> GetAll()
    {
        yield return new gender("Boy", boy);
        yield return new gender("Girl", girl);
    }
```

I want to find a way to give my program the string "Boy" and get as a result the string "B" as it should. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var param = "Boy";
var someBoy = GetAll().Where(g => g.Description == param).Select(g => g.Value).Single();
```

Comment: Use SingleOrDefault() over Single() if a search hit is not guaranteed. SingleOrDefault will return null if no match is found, whereas Single will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same as in prevois answer but with check for wrong value received :)

```
var rez = GetAll().FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Description==string_received);
if(rez==null) throw new ArgumentException();
return rez.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even want to use an IEnumerable method and a Gender class? You should use an Enum in this situation. Define your Enum like this:

```
public Enum Gender { Boy, Girl };
```

Then, you can do this:

```
Gender gender = Gender.Boy;
string description = gender.ToString();

// If you want to use 'B' as value...
string value = description[0];
```

Read more about enums here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum